# Block port 22 on specific Docker container

Tags: docker, firewalld

I have multiple Docker containers on a Centos 7 host and all their network interfaces are added to the Docker firewalld zone.

I only want to block one of the containers from accepting traffic on port 22, not all the containers.

I added:

```
iptables -I DOCKER-USER -p tcp -i br-a4faf253d1ff ! -s 10.2.0.4 --dport 22 -j REJECT
```

but it did not make a difference. How do I block ports on specific interfaces for Docker containers.

Comment: Can't you just not map the port when you run the container? The `-I` in your command means 'insert', and IPTables is order-dependent, so it might just be the rule is in the wrong place.

Comment: When I ran this I did not even see the record added if I run iptables -S

Comment: Sorry, when you ran what? The command in your question? How do you run the actual container?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was someone added a port-forward rule under the firewalld zone for docker that took all port 22 traffic and redirected it to the docker container. Removing this forward fixed my issue.